# .NET 7 Custom AuthorizeAttribute never reaches OnAuthorization method and yet redirects to log in page

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-7.0, authorize-attribute

I have a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` which works great when a user is logged in (and interestingly enough on the production environment) but on my dev machine (using ngrok to handle external requests, a necessary complexity unfortunately) when a new user arrives at a controller method decorated with my `CustomAuthorizeAttribute`:

1. The OnAuthorization() method of the attribute is never reached
2. The user is immediately redirected to the wrong URL https://localhost/Account/Login (which is missing the required port)

Im trying to debug this but am a bit out of my depth. Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to tell since there is not much detail here. Can you please provide some kind of [mre]?

Comment: Therein lies my problem. I cant reproduce the issue even in the production environment. I havent a clue where to start, but am hoping someone who understands the pipeline to the `AuthorizeAttribute` can point me at a possible debugging point?

Comment: From my experience, ngrok is probably the culprit. So [if you are in a dev environment, it is recommended to use vs2022 devtunnel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/dev-tunnels?view=aspnetcore-8.0), you can also [check this if you don't want to use vs2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/get-started?tabs=windows).